# Two Separate Tickets, One Itinerary

Tags: air-travel, tickets, jfk, self-transfer

My brother gifted me a Delta round trip JFK-NCE.
The only blip is that I live in Pittsburgh. So I must buy my own ticket PIT-JFK.

The gifted ticket is on Delta and the purchased ticket is on Delta.

My only concern is if the PIT-JFK segment has problems. This has happened on my last two Delta ticketed round trips to Europe but those were on one itinerary and I was rerouted.
There is a five hour stopover between flights. I am not checking a bag.
I tried to call Delta but the connection with the rep was difficult to understand because of his accent.

Comment: So what is your question?  What you're describing is known as a self-transfer, and it's on you if the PIT-JFK flight arrives late, thereby causing you to miss the JFK-NCE flight.  It doesn't matter that they are both on Delta, though they might out of goodwill put you onto a later flight.

Comment: your brother gave you a plane ticket starting from a place where you don't live?

Comment: Depending on the fare it is sometimes simpler and cheaper to just change the booking to take into account the different origin/destination. It may be the same price as or even cheaper than the original. YMMV of course.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, yes.  So long as the connection time meets same requirements as a single itinerary.

However, while there are numerous report of Delta/SkyTeam doing this regularly, it is apparently not a *published* policy.  Only internal policy I presume.

You can have the two reservations linked, but that doesn't do anything other than the Agent seeing they're linked.

American/OneWorld has this a public policy and I have used it.

Here is a relatively recent thread discussing this this very topic: [Does Delta protect on separate tickets (both on Delta)](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/delta-air-lines-skymiles/2045234-does-delta-protect-separate-tickets-both-delta.html)

Comment: "Short answer, yes" - short answer to what exactly?